# How was Future Okabe sure that Kurisu's death wasn't a convergence point that would inevitably happen?

Tags: steins-gate

We saw in the VN that when Okabe tried to completely isolate Mayuri from danger, she would simply die of a heart attack. So why was future Okabe so sure that it was possible to save Kurisu? Her death could very well have been a convergence point like in Mayuri's case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HEAVY STEINS;GATE 0 SPOILERS, IF YOU HAVEN'T READ THE VN, DON'T READ THIS!**

The answer is not that simple, but here it is in a nutshell:

> In the story of 0, Okabe somehow finds himself in 2036. But, as we know, in the Beta attractor field, he was supposed to die in 2025 no matter what. So, him being in 2036 shouldn't be possible at all. However, after being endlessly tortured by a certain someone, he essentially became brain dead. Later, Daru got hold of Okabe's body, which was still functioning. Without letting anyone find out, Daru and a few other labmems maintained Okabe's body in a hidden facility all the way to the point where they could find Okabe's digitized memories that were saved before. The memories were found in 2036 and loaded back into Okabe's body. Okabe was able to walk the (very much destroyed) earth in 2036. He was alive.

So, THE WORLD WAS DECEIVED. And this is why Okabe knew Kurisu could be saved:

> he himself was alive when he was destined to die years before.

That meant that there was a way to save Kurisu, too. Daru deceived the world, so Okabe decided that he will deceive the world, too.

> [image: The D-RINE]

Comment: There is also another important thing: Kurisu death/survive is a big turning points that generate alpha and beta world lines, but from Okabe point of view he only see Kurisu in a pool of blood and than he travel to the alpha world line. That's the main difference between Mayuri and Kurisu... with Mayuri he experience the consequence (Mayuri death) in the alpha world line (so it would not be able to avoid it), with Kurisu he travel back to beta world line where Kurisu death is already decided but

Comment: he can go back to the turning point and change the fact that he did not experience first hand (since he was in the alpha world line). The only thing that should remain the same is the experience from the Okabe point of view (he cannot change the past or it will go back to the alpha world line) but Okabe did not experience Kurisu death. The world can be deceived not by changing the consequence but by changing the way something happens, Kurisu was "in a pool of blood", Mayuri was "dead" you cannot change those but you can change how.

Answer (score 0):

Kurisu was not subject to Mayuri's Dilemma.

Your argument only holds if you assume it would be a convergent point, but Okabe knows more than you about this situation, especially the future one, as he has thought a lot about it. Thus he managed to deduce that it wasnt a convergent point.

Comment: That was my question really, How did he know it wasn't a convergence point? It seems that convergence points are random like in Mayuri's case she didn't have to die for SERN to build a time machine. All they had to do was knock her unconscious and Kidnap the other lab members

Answer (score 0):

Deceiving the world can only be done in the beta attractor field because the time machine is complete there. There would be no way to save Mayuri because the time machine can only go to the past. That's why the S;G worldline is still in the 1.00+ (beta attractor field)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think Mayuri's death in the alpha world lines is actually pretty important for the world since it became Okabe's reason for firing up resistance against SERN and that makes Daru too and with that, Barrel Titor's time machine was born.